# HAML: f.object (form_for) local passed to partial is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Trying to make an universal partial to display error messages. Passing `f.object` into it. But `object` is `nil` inside my partial.

**new.html.haml**

```rb
= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f|

  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

  %p
    =f.label :title
    =f.text_field :title
  %p
    =f.label :body
    =f.text_area :body

    =f.submit "Create"
```

**shared/_error_messages.html.haml**

```
- if object.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    .alert.alert-danger
      You made
      = pluralize(object.errors.count, "mistake")
      Please fix:
      %ul
        = object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
```

In ERB, this was a no-brainer. Everything is properly indented (I hope) but if I check inside partial via local_assigns, I get `{:object=>nil,:error_messages=>nil}`

Rails 4.2.5, HAML 4.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not have anything to do with HAML.

You're not passing an object to the `form_for`, so `f.object` is really `nil`.

Use `@post = Post.new` in controller and then

```
= form_for @post do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks Vasfed, I just found out the same thing :) Great support, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to render `error_messages` inside the `form_for` block. The way you posted it here - `render` has no indentation, so it's not nested inside `form_for`

Comment: in my code, it is properly indented. it was just an error introduced when copying the code here. the problem must be somewhere else. but good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved it. For some reason, if you do this

```
= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f|
```

it's not going to work. You need to use IVAR `@post` for it to work.

```
= form_for @post, url: posts_path do |f|
```